# Finding a limit with two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, let $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2)$. Find the limit of f(x,y) as $(x,y) \leftrightarrow (0,0)$ along the line y=mx.

By replacing y=mx, I found $f(x,y)=(1-m^2)/(1+m^2)$

Is it possible to define f(0,0) so as to make f continuous at (0,0)

This I didn't know

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a limit $L$ at $(0,0)$ existed, then for every $m$, you would have
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x,mx)=L
$$
since $(x,mx)\rightarrow (0,0)$ when $x\rightarrow 0$.

Given your work, this yields
$$
\frac{1-m^2}{1+m^2}=L\qquad\forall m\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Can you find a contradiction? Try two simple values of $m$.

Comment: No I cannot. Can specify a bit more

Comment: @Carpediem Ok, I edited. And now?

Comment: We get a different limit for different values of m

Comment: @Carpediem Yes, e.g. $m=0$ and $m=1$ yield $L=1$ and $L=0$. Contradiction.

Comment: So the answer to the second question is no

Comment: If there is a continuous extension of $f$ by $f(0,0)=L$ at $(0,0)$, you would have $L=f(0,0)=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} f(x,y)$. So the answer is indeed no.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7842/discussion-between-carpediem-and-julien)